# Flutter build error - Android resource linking failed. even set compileSdkVersion 28

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Please help, I'm facing problem when building realease  apk file as below. I have tried searching but found only to set `compileSdkVersion 28`  in build.gradle file, but unlucky for my case. Any body has suggestion?

````
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                           
                                                                                                                   
* What went wrong:                                                                                                 
Execution failed for task ':flutter_appavailability:verifyReleaseResources'.                                       
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade                  
   > 1 exception was raised by workers:                                                                            
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed                          
     /Users/adsavin/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/855694052351881cfd5b05bbd4ccb2f3/core-1.0.1/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
                                                                                                                   
     /Users/adsavin/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/855694052351881cfd5b05bbd4ccb2f3/core-1.0.1/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                   
* Try:                                                                                                             
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                                                                   
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                                                                         
                                                                                                                   
BUILD FAILED in 1m 58s                                                                                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                                                           
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     122.4s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the
incompatibility.
Building plugin connectivity...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    4.6s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/repo.
Building plugin connectivity_macos...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    5.3s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/repo.
Building plugin firebase_auth...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    4.8s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/repo.
Building plugin firebase_auth_web...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    4.5s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/repo.
Building plugin firebase_core...
The plugin firebase_core could not be built due to the issue above.     
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please migrate your app in android x and if it's already done then please
check your plugin version compatible with android x

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration